# I can't Set Virtual host on my local machine. My Vhost reffer back to Localhost

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, virtualhost

## Info

I am using `Xampp` to host php site on my local for development I have tried every solution i get my hands on but i still can't setup new virtual host on my machine i was having no issue until i update my OS to windows 10 from windows 8.1. My own PC have Linux which gives me no issue at all.
Here are my files Please have a look.

---

## My Hosts File

```
127.0.0.1       lhphoneparts.com www.lhphoneparts.com
127.0.0.1       lhchatsystem.lh www.lhchatsystem.lh
127.0.0.1       lhefficise.lh www.lhefficise.lh
127.0.0.1       lhefficise.com www.lhefficise.com
127.0.0.1       lhwwshoes.com www.lhwwshoes.com
127.0.0.1       lmlicenses.wip4.adobe.com
127.0.0.1       lm.licenses.adobe.com



0.0.0.1 mssplus.mcafee.com
```

---

## V-host.conf File from Xampp

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@oldopencart.lh
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/oldopencart"
    ServerName oldopencart.lh
    ServerAlias www.oldopencart.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/oldopencart.lh-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/oldopencart.lh-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhphoneparts.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/phoneparts"
    ServerName lhphoneparts.com
    ServerAlias www.lhphoneparts.com
    ErrorLog "logs/lhphoneparts.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhphoneparts.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhdoor.lh
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/door"
    ServerName lhdoor.lh
    ServerAlias www.lhdoor.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/lhdoor.lh-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhdoor.lh-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhefficise.lh
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/efficise"
    ServerName lhefficise.lh
    ServerAlias www.lhefficise.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/lhefficise.lh-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhefficise.lh-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhefficise.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/efficise"
    ServerName lhefficise.com
    ServerAlias www.lhefficise.com
    ErrorLog "logs/lhefficise.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhefficise.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhchatsystem.lh
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/chatsystem"
    ServerName lhchatsystem.lh
    ServerAlias www.lhchatsystem.lh
    ErrorLog "logs/lhchatsystem.lh-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhchatsystem.lh-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@lhwwshoes.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/wwshoes"
    ServerName lhwwshoes.com
    ErrorLog "logs/lhwwshoes.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/lhwwshoes.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

---

## Problem

I have all my virtual host set before i update to windows 10 they work fine and still work fine but after updating i start working on this project `wwShoes` and i created 
`lhwwshowes.com` but when i open `lhwwshoes.com` or `www.lhwwshoes.com` it redirect to `localhost/wwshoes` which is my root directory for `lhwwshoes.com`

Hope I'll get exerts for this to get me off this problem
Thanks guys in advance i really appropriate your help
Also let me know if i miss some thing to put in my question feel free to ask.

Comment: Does your lhwwshoes.com VirtualHost have a closing tag `</VirtualHost>`?

Comment: Yes it does sorry it was formation error during writing.